# Defining a phrase containing math and text usable in both math and text mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I would like to define a phrase *once* that contains both math and text, and be able to use usable in *both* math and text mode. For example:

```
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{ and } \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}
```

This works fine in math mode, but leaves too much space in text mode.  Of course:

```
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{and} \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}
```

works fine in text mode, but not in math mode.

Well that led me to:

```
\newcommand{\Space}{\ifmmode{ }\else{}\fi}%
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{\Space and\Space} \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}
```

which of course is a brilliant solution, except for the fact that it only yields correct results in text mode!! I attempted to replace the `{ }` with various math spacing (`\;`, and `\hspace{1ex}`) and they had no effect in math mode.

The one case that does yield correct spacing in both is using an `\mbox` as in:

```
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\mbox{\ensuremath{x \neq 0}  and \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}}
```

but then the text can not be split across line boundaries so is not good enough.

Below are my various failed attempts commented out. The code as below yields:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{showframe}

%%%% Math Mode: Works fine
%%%% Text Mode: Too much space before and after "and"
%\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{ and } \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}

%%%% Math Mode: No space before and after "and"
%%%% Text Mode: Works fine 
%\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{and} \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}


%%%% Math Mode: Works fine
%%%% Text Mode: Too much space before and after "and"
%\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{~and~} \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}


%%%% Math Mode: missing space after "and"
%%%% Text Mode: Too much space before and after "and"
%\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{~and\xspace} \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}

%%%% Math Mode: missing spaces before and after
%%%% Text Mode: Works fine.
\newcommand{\Space}{\ifmmode{ }\else{}\fi}%
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0} \text{\Space and\Space} \ensuremath{x \neq -1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{2x}{x+1} &= \frac {2x-1}{x}\\
    \implies 2x  (x)   &= (x+1) (2x-1) \qquad\Constraint
\end{align*}
%
In a short sentence note the constraint: \Constraint.

In a long sentence note the above the constraint must be satisfied: $\Constraint$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you work around the problem by using the working text-mode-definition, and then use `\text{\Constraint}`? Or perhaps this isn't robust enough...

Comment: @cmhughes: Using the two examples that work fine in math mode and adding `\text{}` around it still yields too much space in `\text` mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** Next try: take the spaces outside `\text`

```
\newcommand\Space{\penalty\z@\hspace{1ex}}
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\ensuremath{x \neq 0\Space\text{and}\Space x \neq -1}}
```

[image: Sample output]

I'd have expected there to be a breakable space for math mode already, so maybe I'm still getting something wrong...

Comment: See updated MWE. This fails when the text crosses line boundaries.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: @PeterGrill It works by @StephanLehmke's way. I added a picture. Your method (and mine) won't break since there is a `\mbox`.

Comment: The only break points are after the two `\neq`.

Comment: @egreg Oops I wasn't aware that `\text` creates a box. New try with breakable space...

Comment: This seems to work fine in my actual use case without the `\penalty\z@`. Can you explain when that is needed?

Comment: @PeterGrill It creates a possible line break. In my image, the line break before the "and" would not be possible without it.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing to do is to say

```
\newcommand{\Constraint}{%
  \relax\ifmmode
    x\neq 0 \text{ and } x\neq 1
  \else
    $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq 1$
  \fi}
```

If one has loaded `babel`, then `\textormath` could be used instead of the conditional, but it's the same concept.

Why not `\ensuremath{x\neq 0 \text{ and } x\neq1}`?

First of all because it uses `\ensuremath`. :) Seriously, because the only break points would be after the relation symbols `\neq`, which is where the break is *less* preferable. The problem is, in fact, that `\text` creates a box.

Add ties and `\nobreak` where it seems suitable. And be careful in defining such abbreviations (that will be mysterious when, a couple of months from now, you'll be again reading the document).

How to avoid repeating the text? *My* solution would be to spell the text without resorting to mysterious abbreviations. Or, if you insist,

```
\newcommand{\ensuretext}[1]{\ifmmode\text{#1}\else#1\fi}
\newcommand{\Constraint}{%
  \ensuremath{x\neq 0}\ensuretext{ and }\ensuremath{x \neq 1}}
```

which is worse than specifying the text twice.

Comment: May I ask (just curiosity), why do you start with `\relax`? Other than that, this is the cleanest solution so far IMHO, because it does exactly what you would do when typesetting it manually.

Comment: @tohecz It's only necessary if `\Constraint` happens to be in a `\halign` cell (for example in a `tabular` environment), because at the start of a cell TeX is in text mode and expands tokens looking for `\omit`. In this case it wouldn't be really necessary, but it's a good habit to prefix `\ifmmode` with `\relax` (unless very special things are needed).

Comment: Is it a good habit with other `if`'s as well?

Comment: @tohecz With `\ifvmode`, for instance, and the reason is the same: at the start of a `\halign` cell TeX is in restricted horizontal mode.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid specifying the constraint twice.  This is all within a small self contained document, so should not be a problem when I come back to it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Look at the edited answer. Trust me: these shorthands are only a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ensuremath` by the `\( \)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\Constraint}{\mbox{\(x \neq 0\)  and \(x \neq -1\)}} %<---- replace \ensure math{} by \( \).
%------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{2x}{x+1} &= \frac {2x-1}{x}\\
    \implies 2x  (x)   &= (x+1) (2x-1) \qquad\Constraint
\end{align*}
%
Note in the above the constraint: \Constraint.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See updated MWE. This fails when the text crosses line boundaries.